# Как повесить одно событие на несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть такой html код

```
<div class="block">
    <div data-test="one">
    one
    </div>
    <div data-test="two">
    two
    </div>
</div>
```

Как можно вызвать разные событие по одному клику в зависимости от того на какой атрибут нажали

Например

```
$('.block').click (
//если нажали на data-test="two" то что то делаем
// если нажали на data-test="one" то делаем другое
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.block > div').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-test') === 'two') {
    console.log('если нажали на data-test="two" то что то делаем')
  } else if ($(this).attr('data-test') === 'one') {
    console.log('если нажали на data-test="one" то делаем другое')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div data-test="one">
    one
  </div>
  <div data-test="two">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно не переносить класс: `$('.block > div').click(`

Comment: @Igor Вы правы, спасибо за уточнение.

Answer (score 2):

У объекта Event есть свойство [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), которое содержит ссылку на целевой (т.е. самый вложенный) элемент DOM структуры, который принял событие. Вы можете прочитать значения атрибутов этого элемента. (для работы с атрибутом data- в jQuery можно использовать метод [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/))

```js
$(function () {
  $('.block').click(function(evt) {
    alert($(evt.target).data('test'))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
    <div data-test="one">
    one
    </div>
    <div data-test="two">
    two
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать прием **делегирование событий**. Он заключается в том, что если у нас есть много элементов, события на которых нужно обрабатывать похожим образом, то вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик каждому – мы ставим один обработчик на их общего предка. Из него можно получить целевой элемент `event.target`, понять на каком именно потомке произошло событие и обработать его.

```js
document
   .querySelector('.container')
   .addEventListener('click',
          event => console.log(event.target.dataset.test))
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-test="one">
    one
  </div>
  <div data-test="two">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```